# heroku python error ' at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running'

Tags: python, django, heroku

I made a simply website using django and am trying to deploy to Heroku.
But I get the following error message when i try to open the web page:

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the 
application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the 
command
heroku logs --tail
```

And this is what i find in the logs:

```
2022-04-10T18:53:57.509376+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes 
running" method=GET path="/" host=safe-earth-20673.herokuapp.com request_id=fdb90caf-8174- 
4ca3-9871-2046f928c959 fwd="62.163.104.251" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
protocol=https
```

If I use the 'heroku local web' command i get this error:

```
[WARN] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Procfile'
[FAIL] No Procfile and no package.json file found in Current Directory - See run-foreman.js -- 
help
```

And this is what is in my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn ullie_diary.wsgi --log-file -
```

My Procfile is in the same directory as manage.py. I also have the requirements.txt and runtime.txt files in the same directory.

I tried this solution:

```
web: gunicorn ullie_diary.wsgi --log-file -
```

But it doesn't work. I've checked out other questions with the same problem on Stack overflow but
can't figure out what the problem is. Can you help me to solve this issue? thank you very much.

Comment: "And this is what is in my Procfile"—wait, `heroku local` just told you you don't _have_ a `Procfile`. Are you entirely sure it's called `Procfile`, _exactly?_ Not `procfile` or `ProcFile` or `Procfile.txt`, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You try run dyno with set manual scaling from heroku cli.

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```